# Undefined index in legacyrouter 3.8.2

Tags: com-content, joomla3.8

I get lots of notices for components/com_content/helpers/legacyrouter.php, like:

"/home/xxx/domains/xxxxxx/public_html/cc_j34/components/com_content/helpers/legacyrouter.php on line 95\nPHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: view in "

I guess that bots are searching for links that don't exist anymore. At the end they get a 404, but I think the legacyrouter shouldn't give this warning.

The code, changed for 3.8.2 is:

```
    if ($menuItem !== null
        && $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view']
        && isset($menuItem->query['id'], $query['id'])
        && $menuItem->query['id'] == (int) $query['id'])
```

with "&& $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view']" as line 95.

Could it be possible that this 'view' is not set? In 3.8.2. a check was added for the query['id'].

Any hint of how to check and fix this....?

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (I use Joomla 3.8.3) and I just found a solution.

The problem is in the exact code that you wrote. You have to change it to:

```
if ($menuItem !== null
            && isset($menuItem->query['view'])
            && $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view']
            && isset($menuItem->query['id'], $query['id'])
            && $menuItem->query['id'] == (int) $query['id'])
```

Actually you have to add the line:

```
&& isset($menuItem->query['view'])
```

(This code exists in the file "components\com_content\helpers\legacyrouter.php".)

It seems that they forgot to check the existence of the variable $menuItem->query['view'].